# Remove `\t` from JSON created from multidimensional array (php)

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am coverting array `$arrData` into JSON using `json_encode()`. I gatherd data from web and put it into php array. The problem is that output is full of tabs. I tried `$arrData = trim(preg_replace('/\t/', '', $arrData));` - but it deletes `\t` and all arrays inside arrays.
Is there a way to remove all `\t` without destroying array structure?

My array:

```
 $arrData = array(
                "chart" => array(
                    "caption" => "Number of visitors last week",
        "subCaption" => "Bakersfield Central vs Los Angeles Topanga",
        "captionFontSize" => "14",
        "subcaptionFontSize" => "14",
        "subcaptionFontBold" => "0",
        "paletteColors" => "#0075c2,#1aaf5d,#FF5733,#33B5FF",
        "bgcolor" => "#ffffff",
        "showBorder" => "0",
        "showShadow" => "0",
        "showCanvasBorder" => "0",
        "usePlotGradientColor" => "0",
        "legendBorderAlpha" => "0",
        "legendShadow" => "0",
        "showAxisLines" => "0",
        "showAlternateHGridColor" => "0",
        "divlineThickness" => "1",
        "divLineDashed" => "1",
        "divLineDashLen" => "1",
        "xAxisName" => "Day",
        "showValues" => "0"
                )
            );
$actualCategory = array( $rowData[0][1], $rowData[0][2], $rowData[0][3], $rowData[0][4], $rowData[0][5], $rowData[0][6], $rowData[0][7]);
                $a = array( 
                array( $rowData[2][1], $rowData[2][2], $rowData[2][3], $rowData[2][4], $rowData[2][5], $rowData[2][6], $rowData[2][7]),
                array( $rowData[5][1], $rowData[5][2], $rowData[5][3], $rowData[5][4], $rowData[5][5], $rowData[5][6], $rowData[5][7]),
                array( $rowData[8][1], $rowData[8][2], $rowData[8][3], $rowData[8][4], $rowData[8][5], $rowData[8][6], $rowData[8][7]),
                array( $rowData[11][1], $rowData[11][2], $rowData[11][3], $rowData[11][4], $rowData[11][5], $rowData[11][6], $rowData[11][7])
                );


                $arrData['categories'] = array();
                $arrData['categories']['category'] = array();
                $arrData['dataset'] = array();



                foreach ($actualCategory as $value) {
                    array_push($arrData['categories']['category'],
                        array(
                            'label' => $value
                        )
                    );
                }

                $q = 1;
                for($z = 0;$z <= 3; $z++){

                $x[$z] = array('seriesname' => $rowData[$q][0], 'data' => array());
                    foreach ($a[$z] as $value) {
                        array_push($x[$z]['data'],
                            array(
                               'value' => $value
                            )
                        );
                    }
                $q = $q + 3;
                }
    $arrData['dataset'] = $x;
```

My JSON code:

```
{
"chart":{
"caption":"Number of visitors last week",
"subCaption":"Bakersfield Central vs Los Angeles Topanga",
"captionFontSize":"14",
"subcaptionFontSize":"14",
"subcaptionFontBold":"0",
"paletteColors":"#0075c2,#1aaf5d,#FF5733,#33B5FF",
"bgcolor":"#ffffff",
"showBorder":"0",
"showShadow":"0",
"showCanvasBorder":"0",
"usePlotGradientColor":"0",
"legendBorderAlpha":"0",
"legendShadow":"0",
"showAxisLines":"0",
"showAlternateHGridColor":"0",
"divlineThickness":"1",
"divLineDashed":"1",
"divLineDashLen":"1",
"xAxisName":"Day",
"showValues":"0"},
"categories":{
"category":[
{"label":" \t \t N. \t 12\/02 \t "},
{"label":" \t \t Pn. \t 13\/02 \t "},
{"label":" \t \t Wt. \t 14\/02 \t "},
{"label":" \t \t \u015ar. \t 15\/02 \t "},
{"label":" \t \t Cz. \t 16\/02 \t "},
{"label":" \t \t Pt. \t 17\/02 \t "},
{"label":" \t \t So. \t 18\/02 \t "}]},
"dataset":[
{
"seriesname":" \t IRDN \t ",
"data":[
{"value":" \t 142.59 \t "},
{"value":" \t 174.88 \t "},
{"value":" \t 176.97 \t "},
{"value":" \t 182.48 \t "},
{"value":" \t 160.15 \t "},
{"value":" \t 160.72 \t "},
{"value":" \t 165.47 \t "}]},
{
"seriesname":" \t \t \t SIRDN \t \t ",
"data":[{"value":" \t 148.81 \t \t "},
{"value":" \t 197.29 \t \t "},
{"value":" \t 202.27 \t \t "},
{"value":" \t 211.93 \t \t "},
{"value":" \t 177.87 \t \t "},
{"value":" \t 179.37 \t \t "},
{"value":" \t 177.69 \t \t "}]},
{
"seriesname":" \t \t IRDN24 \t \t ",
"data":[{"value":" \t 140.31 \t \t "},
{"value":" \t 174.50 \t \t "},
{"value":" \t 180.38 \t \t "},
{"value":" \t 187.70 \t \t "},
{"value":" \t 161.91 \t \t "},
{"value":" \t 161.62 \t \t "},
{"value":" \t 160.98 \t \t "}]},
{
"seriesname":" \t \t IRDN 8.22 \t \t ",
"data":[{"value":" \t 147.33 \t "},
{"value":" \t 197.02 \t "},
{"value":" \t 202.21 \t "},
{"value":" \t 211.28 \t "},
{"value":" \t 178.11 \t "},
{"value":" \t 179.32 \t "},
{"value":" \t 176.31 \t "}
]}]}
```

Comment: remove `\t` from your json data. is it possible?

Comment: $smoqadam Yes I would like to remove all `\t` from array or JSON. I need only clear values.

Comment: you can use `array_walk()` and call the function recursively if the element is an array.. Half an hour and I may write an example

Comment: @ShadyAtef Thanks but it is already solved by AbraCadaver :)

Comment: Another solution, I was gonna remove them in the array before encoding.

Comment: @ShadyAtef So if you have time and idea I would like to see it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace them in the JSON. Make sure to use single-quotes:

```
$json = str_replace('\t', '', $json);
```

Your regex will also work but you need three `\`:

```
$json = preg_replace('/\\\t/', '', $json);
```

To get the `\t` and surrounding spaces use:

```
$json = preg_replace('/(\s+)?\\\t(\s+)?/', '', $json);
```

Comment: The last one doesn't delete all spaces. For example for values I get ` 142.59 ` so it deletes space and tab. Is it possible to delte space tab and sapce?

Comment: It worked with your sample data, but I updated the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
function clear_array(&$arr)
{
        array_walk($arr,function (&$value,$key)
        {
                if(gettype($value)=='array')
                        clear_array($value);

                else if(gettype($value)=='string'){
                        $value= preg_replace('/[\s]/', '', $value);
                }
        });
}
```

Pass your array and it will remove all spaces from values.

---

JSON output

```
{
    "chart": {
        "caption": "Numberofvisitorslastweek",
        "subCaption": "BakersfieldCentralvsLosAngelesTopanga",
        "captionFontSize": "14",
        "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
        "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
        "paletteColors": "#0075c2,#1aaf5d,#FF5733,#33B5FF",
        "bgcolor": "#ffffff",
        "showBorder": "0",
        "showShadow": "0",
        "showCanvasBorder": "0",
        "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
        "legendBorderAlpha": "0",
        "legendShadow": "0",
        "showAxisLines": "0",
        "showAlternateHGridColor": "0",
        "divlineThickness": "1",
        "divLineDashed": "1",
        "divLineDashLen": "1",
        "xAxisName": "Day",
        "showValues": "0"
    },
    "categories": {
        "category": [
            {
                "label": "N.12/02"
            },
            {
                "label": "Pn.13/02"
            },
            {
                "label": "Wt.14/02"
            },
            {
                "label": "Śr.15/02"
            },
            {
                "label": "Cz.16/02"
            },
            {
                "label": "Pt.17/02"
            },
            {
                "label": "So.18/02"
            }
        ]
    },
    "dataset": [
        {
            "seriesname": "IRDN",
            "data": [
                {
                    "value": "142.59"
                },
                {
                    "value": "174.88"
                },
                {
                    "value": "176.97"
                },
                {
                    "value": "182.48"
                },
                {
                    "value": "160.15"
                },
                {
                    "value": "160.72"
                },
                {
                    "value": "165.47"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "seriesname": "SIRDN",
            "data": [
                {
                    "value": "148.81"
                },
                {
                    "value": "197.29"
                },
                {
                    "value": "202.27"
                },
                {
                    "value": "211.93"
                },
                {
                    "value": "177.87"
                },
                {
                    "value": "179.37"
                },
                {
                    "value": "177.69"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "seriesname": "IRDN24",
            "data": [
                {
                    "value": "140.31"
                },
                {
                    "value": "174.50"
                },
                {
                    "value": "180.38"
                },
                {
                    "value": "187.70"
                },
                {
                    "value": "161.91"
                },
                {
                    "value": "161.62"
                },
                {
                    "value": "160.98"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "seriesname": "IRDN8.22",
            "data": [
                {
                    "value": "147.33"
                },
                {
                    "value": "197.02"
                },
                {
                    "value": "202.21"
                },
                {
                    "value": "211.28"
                },
                {
                    "value": "178.11"
                },
                {
                    "value": "179.32"
                },
                {
                    "value": "176.31"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I have passed my data array into this function but it completely deleted it. when I echo a result i got `null`. 
`$arrData = clear_array($arrData);
$jsonEncodedData = json_encode($arrData);
echo $jsonEncodedData;`

Comment: I used your json input as a test via the following line `$arr = json_decode($x,$assoc=true); clear_array($arr);` 
And it works great

Comment: I am glad that it helped