# Is there a way to not prettify arrays when using json_encode with JSON_PRETTY_PRINT?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I know this might not be possible using `json_encode` alone, but then what would be the best way? (preferrably not using an external library)

You can obviously imagine I don't feel like writing my own json encoder.

Here is an example of what I would like it to look like:

```json
{
   "someString": "hello",
   "someObject": {
      "someInteger": 123
   },
   "someArray": ["foo","bar","baz"] // Like this!
}
```

Instead of currently, using the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` flag:

```json
{
   "someString": "hello",
   "someObject": {
      "someInteger": 123
   },
   "someArray": [ // Ewww
      "foo",
      "bar",
      "baz"
   ]
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You you just want all the array values on the same line? Isn't that just a visual difference, programatically they're the same, no?

Comment: @user3783243 This outputs to a setting file, which is also subject to be manually edited from time to time. Having arrays on the same line would make it way easier to read and edit for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304075/remove-t-from-json-created-from-multidimensional-array-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first tried to use RegEx, sadly it didn't seem "easily" possible considering there is no way to create a dynamic number of capture groups, and that's what I was aiming to do.

So, I ended up writing my own piece of code that rewrites and minifies arrays in an already prettified JSON. Here is the function:

```php
function minifyJsonArrays($json)
{
    $minifiedJson = "";
    $inArray = false;

    foreach (explode(PHP_EOL, $json) as $line)
    {
        if (str_ends_with($line, '['))
        {
            $inArray = true;
            $minifiedJson .= $line;
        }
        else if (str_ends_with($line, ']') || str_ends_with($line, '],'))
        {
            $inArray = false;
            $minifiedJson .= trim($line) . PHP_EOL;
        }
        else if ($inArray)
        {
            $minifiedJson .= trim($line) /*. " "*/;
        }
        else
        {
            $minifiedJson .= $line . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    return $minifiedJson;
}
```

It's probably not the best solution, I'm sure there's something simpler, but I think it remains clean and even then it perfectly does the job, as you can see on this picture of my newly formatted JSON:

[TADA!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJtNN.jpg)